# Does a conservative monoidal functor between closed symmetric monoidal categories reflect dualizability?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(C, \otimes, [,])$ be a closed symmetric monoidal category, $F: C \to D$ a conservative monoidal functor into another such gadget and $X$ an object of $C$ such that $F(X)$ has a (strong) dual in $D$. Is $X$ dualizable in $C$?

I would expect the answer to be no, as for non-closed $F$ I see no way to produce the necessary maps in $C$. However I could not come up with a counterexample and I am not sure if there isn't some argument I'm overlooking which makes $F$ compatible with special internal homs like $[X,X]$ and $[X, \mathbb{1}]$.

(For what's it worth: I stumbled upon this question when learning about motives; I wondered if conservativity of a realization would also imply that one can check smoothness on the realized side)

Answer (score 4):

On second thought, the following should be an easy counterexample: Let $C$ be the category of finite sets, with $\otimes$ the cartesian product and $[,]$ just maps of sets and let $D$ be the category of finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces with the usual structure.

Then the functor $F: C \to D$ which sends a set to the free vector space on it (plus some coherence data) is a strong monoidal functor which is conservative. However, no object except the one point set in $C$ is dualizable, whereas all objects in $D$ are.